# Can Upload MySQL Database Tables, But Can't Add Values

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

I am able to create a database in phpMyAdmin. When I add only tables, a database is created. Now, I am trying to add values into the `Purchase` table. I keep getting errors that either `Duplicate entry '1' for key 'PRIMARY'` or that there is an error with the syntax.

Here is what I've tried so far:

1. Removing the `PRIMARY KEY` and `auto increment` on P_ORDERNO, and then trying to add the values
2. Adding only one row with one value
3. Adding only one row with the primary key and one other value

My testing through adding and subtracting values/data definitions is not showing any possible errors. Here is the original table with the original values I tried to input:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `Purchase` (
  `P_ORDERNO` int(5) NOT NULL auto_increment PRIMARY KEY,
  `P_ORDER_DATE` timestamp NULL,
  `P_ORDER_AMT` int NOT NULL,
  `SUPPLY_CODE` int(5) NOT NULL,
  `SUPPLY_DESC` varchar(50) NULL,
  `SUPPLY QTY` int(5) NOT NULL
);

INSERT INTO `Purchase` (`P_ORDERNO`, `P_ORDER_DATE`, `P_ORDER_AMT`, `SUPPLY_CODE`, `SUPPLY_DESC`, `SUPPLY_QTY`) VALUES
(1, 2015-08-01 08:15:00, 30, 999, 'Hard drive', 300),
(2, 2015-08-02 08:15:00, 45, 999, 'Mouse', 310),
(3, 2015-08-03 08:15:00, 99, 784, 'Keyboard', 543);
```

I would appreciate any feedback as to what might be the error in my syntax or in my attempts to add values into the database table.

Comment: There might be other issues, but for one the datetime literals needs to be in quotes like this: `'2015-08-01 08:15:00'`

Comment: `not null` on a pk is not necessary to type, fyi

Comment: @Drew, thanks, that makes sense

Comment: @jpw, thanks. that was one of the errors

Comment: sometimes people change the create table statement, run it, think all was well in paradise, then realize they forgot to see the failed attempt (table already exists error). So try as you might, the old structure is still there, data too, the PK violations will still happen, blah blah blah

Comment: yes, i agree. i am expecting to come across a few errors, but i guess ill handle them as i go

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The datetime literals needs to be in quotes like this: `'2015-08-01 08:15:00'` and you're also have a column name wrong in the table def.: (`SUPPLY QTY`instead of `SUPPLY_QTY`).

This works:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `Purchase` (
  `P_ORDERNO` int(5) NOT NULL auto_increment PRIMARY KEY,
  `P_ORDER_DATE` timestamp NULL,
  `P_ORDER_AMT` int NOT NULL,
  `SUPPLY_CODE` int(5) NOT NULL,
  `SUPPLY_DESC` varchar(50) NULL,
  `SUPPLY_QTY` int(5) NOT NULL
);

INSERT INTO `Purchase` (`P_ORDERNO`, `P_ORDER_DATE`, `P_ORDER_AMT`, `SUPPLY_CODE`, `SUPPLY_DESC`, `SUPPLY_QTY`) VALUES
(1, '2015-08-01 08:15:00', 30, 999, 'Hard drive', 300),
(2, '2015-08-02 08:15:00', 45, 999, 'Mouse', 310),
(3, '2015-08-03 08:15:00', 99, 784, 'Keyboard', 543);
```

[Sample SQl Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/c7387/1)

The only column that you can get a duplicate error on given your sample table def and data is the primary key and as the sample data doesn't have any duplicates maybe there's something else going on, or you are not showing the actual data causing the issues in which case it's hard to tell what might be the issue.

Comment: Yes, those were the two issue keeping me from uploading the data. I tried your recommendations and it was able to upload just fine. Thank you!